# Meteor mongo query by nested array field

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

I have a mongo document that look like this:

```
{ theArray: [{type: 'download', expiration: Date}, {type: 'download', expiration: Date}] }
```

I want to query documents to make sure their expiration date is not earlier than the current time but only determined by the expiration in the array object with type 'download'. I was using $elmMatch to try to get the correct data like so:

```
return documents.find({ 
    "userId": user._id,
    "theArray": {
    $elemMatch: {type: 'download', expiration: {$gte: currentTime }
    }
}
```

This is just returning no data and I can not seem to get the behavior im looking for.

Comment: Typo? `$elemMatch`

Comment: Your query with `$elemMatch` looks correct. Is your `currentTime` variable in the same date format as the dates you have stored in the database?